# sqlcmd return only count - suppress text

Tags: bash, sqlcmd

I have a bash file which executes a SQLCMD query to check for the existence of a database:

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P $SA_PASSWORD -d master -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON SELECT count(*) FROM master.sys.databases WHERE name = N'MyDatabaseHere'")
```

I tried adding the `SET NOCOUNT ON` but it still outputs like this:

```
------

1
```

I am assigning the result to a variable and I want to be able to check it like this

```
myvariable == 1
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Took me a while but I found a solution only using sqlcmd.

You need to use `-W -h-1 -k`

`-W` removes trailing space

`-h-1` removes headers

`-k` Removes all    control characters, such as tabs and new line characters from the    output.

```
TABLENAME=$(/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P $SA_PASSWORD -d master -W -h-1 -k -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON SELECT name FROM master.sys.databases WHERE name = N'MyDatabaseNameHere'")
```